# Is it normal to start your master's study without an advisor?

Tags: masters, advisor, united-states, research-assistantship, research-topic

So I've been admitted to master's program in Mechanical Engineering at a US university.

I contacted 2 of the faculty in the department in my chief area of interest , but neither had an opening/ funding . I feel like it was a huge blunder on my part. Should I try to find an advisor in a different subfield or wait a semester and see if any new opening arrive?

If I start research in a different subfield and a spot opens up in my preferred subfield next semester,  is it possible to switch?

Comment: Which country? In certain countries (e.g Italy) you don't get any advisor during your Master's studies up to the last year, when you start working on your thesis and, even then, you don't get any funding (or you get it very rarely for exceptional reasons).

Comment: I'm afraid I'm rather confused by the whole question here.  Can you please try to clarify the situation?

Comment: The country is the USA.

Comment: What do you need clarified Jake. I was accepted into a Master's program. I don't have an advisor. I contacted 2 prospective advisors , but neither was taking in new students. Should I take on an advisor in a different subfield or wait to see if one of them gets an opening.

Comment: The way you're writing is rather confusing. You're stating you've `decided to accept admission` but you're also stating that there's no opening / funding. / Do you mean you're accepted to an MA but don't yet have someone to advise you on your thesis? or do you mean you're not accepted but have a university you want to go to but the professor don't want to accept you there ???

Comment: You should check the department's policies.  Sometimes an advisor is mandatory, sometimes it is forbidden.

Comment: In the US, in most programs I'm familiar with, you first start on coursework.  Some programs are all coursework.  What did the department tell you is expected in terms of research/finding an advisor?

Comment: @virmaior I'm admitted into the program. I'm looking to join a professor's research group , but both of the 2 professors I contacted said they weren't going to advise any more students in the fall because they didn't have funding for a new student.

Comment: @DanieleDeRossi it might be helpful to indicate the field. (in my field, (philosophy) masters degrees don't generally supply funding or require one to find an advisor as a condition of any sort).

Comment: I'm in Mechanical engineering

Comment: You are asking multiple questions: 
Is it normal to start master's without an advisor? 
should i find a different advisor?
is it possible to switch once started? All will have different answers, can you focus your questions into one, so that an answer can be developed?

Answer (score 2):

Well this is more like an advice rather than an answer:
In the end all of it depends on the funding you might receive. If the advisors are sure to be available with the funding next semester, I would say you don't need to hurry to find a new research area. I assume you are interested and made some preparations for your current field. It would be reckless to throw away the work you have done so far.
However if the funding is not so sure for the next semester, I would say you go with the one that supplies you funding. In the end, you can always turn back to your old questions. Researcher is very much like a qualified worker, you are paid not only for the results you've obtained, but mostly you have the capacity to treat and obtain the result or rather they pay you because it is you who has the capacity to treat and obtain the result, so one should not take research subjects at a personal level, at least not too much.
However I have no idea how US works, so you are on your own concerning the feasiblity of my advice.